# Highcharts - center placement of columns

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts column chart and I am trying to reduce the distance between each column on the X axis whilst pulling them towards the center so that the columns appear more grouped.

[image]

So for example in my example above, the red and the blue column would be much closer together and positioned towards the center.

Below is my chart configuration. The seriesData parameter is just a custom object I pass in at render.

**chartConfig.js**

```
function chartConfig(seriesData) {
  return {
    barColor: seriesData.color,
    data: seriesData,
    credits: { enabled: false },
    chart: {
      width: seriesData.width,
      defaultSeriesType: 'column',
      backgroundColor: '#EAEFF6'
    },
    tooltip: { enabled: false },
    colorAxis: {
      dataClassColor: 'category'
    },
    colors: [],
    legend: {},
    title: {
      useHTML: true,
      text: (seriesData.name === 'n/a' || seriesData.name === 'N/A') ? '_' : seriesData.name,
      style: {
        color: (seriesData.name === 'n/a' || seriesData.name === 'N/A') ? '#E9EFF4' : '#666666',
        fontSize: '14px',
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        paddingTop: '10px',
        lineHeight: '1em'
      },
      align: 'center',
      x: 0,
      y: 2
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        animation: true,
        borderColor: 'grey',
        borderWidth: 0
      },
      series: {
        borderRadius: 15,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        states: {
          hover: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      }
    },
    yAxis: [{
      max: Math.max.apply(null, seriesData.scaleValues),
      min: Math.min.apply(null, seriesData.scaleValues),
      title: false,
      minorGridLineColor: '#FFF',
      gridLineColor: '#8E8E8E',
      minPadding: 0,
      tickPositions: (seriesData.scalePercentageValues || null),
      labels: {
        formatter: function () {
          if (seriesData.usePercentage) {
            return `${this.value} %`;
          }
          return this.value;
        }
      }
    }],
    xAxis: {
      lineWidth: 0,
      minorGridLineWidth: 0,
      lineColor: 'transparent',
      minorTickLength: 0,
      tickLength: 0,
      categories: seriesData.elements.map((x) => { return x.name; }),
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: '#666666',
          fontSize: '12px',
          fontFamily: 'Roboto'
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      dataLabels: {
        style: {
          fontSize: '12px',
          fontWeight: 'normal',
          textShadow: 'none',
          color: 'black',
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          backgroundColor: 'blue'
        },
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function () {
          if (seriesData.usePercentage) {
            return `${this.y}%`;
          }
          return this.y;
        }
      },
      showInLegend: false,
      name: 'Fill Series',
      color: '#F2F6F9',
      pointWidth: 28,
      animation: true,
      data: seriesData.elements.map((x) => {
        return { name: x.name, y: x.value, color: x.color };
      }),
      borderRadiusTopLeft: 10,
      borderRadiusTopRight: 10,
      borderColor: '#C0C0C0',
      borderWidth: '1'
    }]
  };
}

module.exports = chartConfig;
```

The only solution I have tried so far is to use pointPadding and groupPadding. However this does not seem to have the desired effect.

Comment: You can set [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.pointRange) parameter and adapt [pointPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.pointRange) and [groupPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.pointRange)